# How do you start multiple node.js apps using forever and upstart?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, node.js, upstart

I'm managing multiple node.js processes using forever, and I need them to start at boot time. I think that upstart should be used for that, but I'm not sure whether I should create one init script per node.js app, or only one init script that starts all the node apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one .conf but give it an `instance` stanza. See the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#instance) for more info and examples. This one won't have a start or stop stanza.

Then you can create another .conf to act as a pidless 'pony engine' to start/stop all the instances at boot/shutdown. This one will have your start/stop stanzas. This way you can control each individual app, or all at once. Again see the cookbook for an example of this.